# Quick assistance with simple python(Learning Lists)

Tags: python

I was learning how to use loops and was doing this program for practice. However, the only thing I am having some difficulty with is printing the list **only once for each input** correctly. Here is my code:

```
country_list=[]
emission_list=[]
capita_list=[]
total=0
end_loop=False
together=[]

while True:
    country=raw_input("Enter country or (done to end): ")
    if country=="done":
        break
    else:
        emission=input("Enter emissions: ")
        capita=input("Enter capita: ")

        country_list.append(country)
        emission_list.append(emission)
        capita_list.append(capita)
        total+=1

for x in range(len(country_list)):
    for y in range(len(emission_list)):
        for z in range(len(capita_list)):
            end_loop=True
            print country_list[x]+": Emission="+str(emission_list[y]),"and Capita="+str(capita_list[z])
```

I am inputting this:

```
Enter country or (done to end): Testcase
Enter emissions: 1
Enter capita: 2
Enter country or (done to end): Testcase2
Enter emissions: 3
Enter capita: 4
Enter country or (done to end): done
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Testcase: Emission=1 and Capita=2
Testcase: Emission=1 and Capita=4
Testcase: Emission=3 and Capita=2
Testcase: Emission=3 and Capita=4
Testcase2: Emission=1 and Capita=2
Testcase2: Emission=1 and Capita=4
Testcase2: Emission=3 and Capita=2
Testcase2: Emission=3 and Capita=4
```

It is printing all possible combinations of the emissions and capita but I only want it to print what I inputted as emissions/capita for each country. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
for x in range(len(country_list)):
    for y in range(len(emission_list)):
        for z in range(len(capita_list)):
            print country_list[x]+": Emission="+str(emission_list[y]),"and Capita="+str(capita_list[z])
```

Do this:

```
for x in range(len(country_list)):
    print country_list[x]+": Emission="+str(emission_list[x]),"and Capita="+str(capita_list[x])
```

Note: Your code will be more meaningfully structured if you create a class that has one country name, one emission and one capita. Then a mistake like this would be impossible since you'd only have one list of objects to iterate over, anyway.

Comment: Also, do you know how I can add together all the emissions for all the countries I inputted?

Answer (score 4):

This is ok as a learning exercise, but the Pythonic way to perform this task is to use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
for cnty, em, cap in zip(country_list, emission_list, capita_list):
    print "{}: Emission={} and Capita={}".format(cnty, em, cap)
```

Actually you should store the results that way (a list of 3-tuples) instead of with three lists that you zip together later.

```
cecs = []

while True:
    country  = raw_input("Enter country (or nothing to end): ").strip()
    if not country:
        break
    emission = input("Enter emissions: ").strip()
    capita   = input("Enter capita: ").strip()

    cecs.append((country, emission, capita))

# total = len(cecs)

for cec in cecs:
    print "{}: Emission={} and Capita={}".format(*cec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a dictionary instead. It'd look like something like this:

```
countries = {}
while True:
    inp = input("Enter country or (done to end): ")
    if inp == 'done':
        break;
    countries[inp] = {'emission': input("Enter emissions: ")}
    countries[inp]['capita']   = input("Enter capita: ")

for i in countries:
    print(i, 'Emission:', countries[i]['emission'],
          'and Capita', countries[i]['capita'])
```

Input:

```
Enter country or (done to end): test
Enter emissions: 1
Enter capita: 2
Enter country or (done to end): test2
Enter emissions: 3
Enter capita: 4
Enter country or (done to end): done
```

Ouput:

```
test Emission: 1 and Capita 2
test2 Emission: 3 and Capita 4
```

At the end the dictionary looks like that:

```
{'test': {'emission': '1', 'capita': '2'}, 'test2': {'emission': '3', 'capita': '4'}}
```